# Getting an xml file error

Tags: android

When I add an xml and name it, first of all, it wont let me put it under the folder I create because, the name of the folder doesnt show up. But when I put the xml file under value or menu. I get a root error

Comment: People will hardly be able to answer your question in its current form. Please restate and specify more clearly what you want to achieve *and* what you already tried

Answer (score 1):

You can put your own custom XML files in `res/raw` or `res/xml`. You can also put them in the `assets` folder, where you can preserve the original file name and folder hierarchy. You cannot put your own XML files in your source code tree or directly in the root `res` folder.

See the guide topic [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: So i created a folder called treasure and created a treasure.xml no layout so, i do I display it in my java code. When I run it, i want the content in the xml to display in my edit text.

Comment: @user2089542 - If you put the file in your `res/raw` folder, you can open an InputStream as described Providing Resources. You can then wrap that in an `InputStreamReader` and read all the xml as text and set it as the text for your EditText view. Note that you'll have to save it somewhere else; you cannot modify assets or resources packaged with the .apk at run time.

Comment: how do I write the code to an edittext or a textview